# Python Tkinter Logo Image not appearing on GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to put a logo in the upper left-hand corner of my window, but I am getting a completely blank window even though my logo is *not* the same color as the background. It is giving me no errors, which is making it difficult to troubleshoot.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def createTopPage():
    img = PhotoImage(file="CMACLOGO.png")
    label = Label(app, image=img)
    label.pack()


app = Tk()
screenHeight = app.winfo_screenheight()
screenWidth = app.winfo_screenwidth()
app.geometry("{0}x{1}".format(screenWidth,screenHeight))
createTopPage()
app.mainloop()
```

Thank you for any help/insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def createTopPage():
    image = Image.open("CMACLOGO.png")
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label = Label(app, image=img)
    label.image = img
    label.pack()

app = Tk()
screenHeight = app.winfo_screenheight()
screenWidth = app.winfo_screenwidth()
app.geometry("{0}x{1}".format(screenWidth, screenHeight))
createTopPage()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working  for me :). Question: why is ```label.image = img``` necessary if we already have ```label = Label(app, image=img)```?

Comment: Adding `label.image = img` is necessary to keep a reference to the image object within the Tkinter Label widget, preventing it from being garbage collected and ensuring that the image is displayed correctly in the GUI.